# Impersonation in Asp.net for Upload a file

Tags: c#, asp.net, security, iis-7, impersonation

Please consider this scenario:

I have a web site that host behind `IIS 7.0` . Almost every `IIS` setting are defaulr settings. I have a folder for upload files that `ASP.Net` user had write access to it.currently `IIS` manager cancel this write access and he want to add a local user in `Windows Server` that this user can has write access to that folder. Now my question is how I can Impersonate user in asp.net and if this method is secure? I want all the request execute on server according to default `IIS` user but I want just impersonate for upload a file.

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need is partial impersonation. you don't need all request to be impersonated but only a few call should be impersonated. i think you must have a look at this article.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306158

this is how it impersonate a piece of code under logged in user's credentials while rest of the call will be processed using default app Pool identity

```
System.Security.Principal.WindowsImpersonationContext impersonationContext;
impersonationContext = 
    ((System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity)User.Identity).Impersonate();

//Insert your code that runs under the security context of the authenticating user here.

impersonationContext.Undo();
```

Comment: thanks but where I should send Username and Password?I mean I want Impersonate using another user?

Comment: in the article there is section for "Impersonate a Specific User in Code". using this you can pass custom username and password to impersonate and then you have to undo that impersonation.

Comment: Is there any way that does not use `API` call?

Comment: well in that case you will have to deploy another web site/web service with app pool identity set the whatever you want and then call the web site / web service in your code.

Comment: in this article:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc949004.aspx in section :`How do I impersonate a specific (fixed) identity?` How I can pass login token of authenticated user to `WindowsIdentity`?